# Simple debounce function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Given a debounce function as below:

```
const debounce = (fn, delay) => {
  let timer;
  return () => {
    if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(fn, delay)
  }
}

document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener('click', debounce(()=>console.log("Clicked"),1000))
```

Every time the button is triggered, it makes a call to the "debounce" function, my question is how could the "timer" variable not being re-initialized? As far as I'm aware, the "let" keyword scope is block-scoped, then how could the "timer" hold the setTimeOut identification from the last call?

Every comment is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: _"Every time the button is triggered, it makes a call to the "debounce" function"_ - No, it doesn't. `debounce()` is called once (add a `console.log(...)` before the `return`), and the return value of it (the inner function) is used as the event handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Every time the button is triggered, it makes a call to the "debounce" function...

No, it's only called once — when you add the event handler. The code `.addEventListener('click', debounce(()=>console.log("Clicked"),1000))` **calls** `debounce` and passes its return value into `addEventListener`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`. The return value of `debounce` is a function; that function is what's passed to `addEventListener` and so *that* function is what gets called each time the event occurs, not `debounce`.

That's why there's only one `timer` variable, because there's only one call to `debounce`. The function it returns closes over the variable.

---

In comments you've asked for a bit of clarification:

> Just another related question, when the "debounce" returns the inner function, which gets passed onto the "addEventListener", does the returned function stay the same after another couple more 'click' event?

Yes. It's one function. This code:

```
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener('click', debounce(()=>console.log("Clicked"),1000));
```

is exactly the same as this code, other than that this code has an identifier the code above doesn't:

```
const eventHandlerFunction = debounce(()=>console.log("Clicked"),1000);
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener('click', eventHandlerFunction);
```

> Another saying for the question is: does the execution context of the returned function not being re-created every time the button is clicked

The execution context for the call to `debounce` is only created once, when you call `debounce`. That execution context contains the `timer` variable. The context (and thus the variable) are retained as long as something has a reference to them. The function `debounce` creates (`eventHandlerFunction` in the code above) has a reference to them, so they exist as long as that function exists.

> (Because the "denounce" function execution is already gone after the first button click, the "timer" variable isn't there anymore after the first button click I should say.)?

The `timer` variable continues to exist as long as the `eventHandlerFunction` continues to exist. That function will continue to exist until all references to it are released — in this case, either by removing it from the element's `click` event handler list, or when the element itself goes away.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, my bad for not paying attention to that in the first place.

Comment: @JadenB - It's a really easy mistake to make. :-)

Comment: Just another related question, when the "debounce" returns the inner function, which gets passed onto the "addEventListener", does the returned function stay the same after another couple more 'click' event? Another saying for the question is: does the execution context of the returned function not being re-created every time the button is clicked (Because the "denounce" function execution is already gone after the first button click, the "timer" variable isn't there anymore after the first button click I should say.)?

Comment: @JadenB - I've updated the answer to try to answer those questions. You may find my old blog post [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) useful (although it uses some outdated terminology), as well as the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). Happy coding!

Comment: " The context (and thus the variable) are retained as long as something has a reference to them. The function debounce creates (eventHandlerFunction in the code above) has a reference to them, so they exist as long as that function exists."-This answers exactly the question that I've been trying to ask. Thank you sooooooooo much for this!!!